# Postfix / SpamAssassin ignoring SPF entirely

Tags: dns, postfix, spamassassin

I am currently getting a ton of email from "myself" and have been having a ton of difficulty filtering it. I have postfix configured to check SPF and (presumably) reject if it fails, and SpamAssassin has the SPF filter installed. But nothing is working. I can connect to postfix over telnet and plaintext a message from "myself" to myself without authentication and it just arrives in my inbox like it's supposed to be there.

```
$ sudo -u spamd -H spamassassin -D --lint 2>&1 | grep SPF
May 24 10:12:04.282 [15707] dbg: diag: [...] module installed: Mail::SPF, version v2.008
May 24 10:12:04.289 [15707] dbg: plugin: loading Mail::SpamAssassin::Plugin::SPF from @INC
```

relevant bits of master.cf

```
...
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd -o content_filter=spamassassin
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd -o content_filter=spamassassin
smtps     inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd -o content_filter=spamassassin
policyd-spf unix - n n - - spawn user=nobody argv=/bin/python /usr/libexec/postfix/policyd-spf
spamassassin unix - n n - - pipe flags=R user=spamd argv=/usr/bin/spamc -e /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${recipient}
...
```

Excerpt main.cf

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    permit_mynetworks,
    check_policy_service unix:private/policyd-spf,
    reject_unauth_destination,
    reject_rhsbl_reverse_client dbl.spamhaus.org,
    reject_rhsbl_helo dbl.spamhaus.org,
    reject_rhsbl_sender dbl.spamhaus.org,
    reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org
```

and I have the SPF defined in the txt records in my DNS (I relay all mail through mailjet due to network restrictions):

`example.com.             20020   IN      TXT     "v=spf1 include:spf.mailjet.com ?all"`

**Edit:** Per suggestion, I have updated my DNS, though the exact behavior still exists:

`example.com.             86400   IN      TXT     "v=spf1 include:spf.mailjet.com -all"`

**Edit 2:** I added a DMARC record to enforce quarantine on 100% of violations, and it's still not working:

`_DMARC.example.com.      86400   IN      TXT     "v=DMARC1; p=quarantine; rua=mailto:postmaster@example.com; ruf=mailto:dmarc-failures@example.com; fo=1; pct=100"`

and I've checked SPF and DMARC with mxtoolbox, and everything looks good.

but Postfix just passes the mail right on through, and SA tacks on `SPF_NEUTRAL` in the header. So......... how do I make this work? How can I prevent this garbage email from coming through?

Edit: I don't care if SA or Postfix blocks it, I just don't want it in my inbox. I think I may have mixed up trying to integrate both blocking and that's why it's not working? Or did I misconfigure my DNS?

**Edit 3:** According to Method 2 here: https://serverfault.com/questions/905591/receiving-spam-from-my-own-email-address-postfix this should be working? (This question is older and uses the perl module, whereas I'm using the newer python module, but I implemented it the same way.)

Comment: It should be -all, and SPF by itself might not be enough.

Comment: Thanks @RuiFRibeiro, I've updated my DNS to have `-all` but I still get the `SPF_NEUTRAL` header

Comment: SPF by itself in the DNS is a "recommendation". You have to do the setup on your side for filtering too. I would have a look to DMARC also.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Thanks again! I have postfix running against the SPF check utility, and I have SpamAssassin running the SPF check. I've also set up DMARC to quarantine 100% of violations... still not working. absolutely no change in behavior. I'm not sure what else there is to set up?

Comment: How is the DMARC setup on the email server side? It is not enough to set it up on the DNS side.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro if I'm explicitly telling postfix & SA to check SPF records why do I need DMARC? I don't care if other servers enforce my SPF rules. It seems the only solution for enforcing I can find is opendmarc, and it's been described as "buggy but usually functional" and from what I've read I should be able to block this kind of spam without DMARC. Also  I'm not using DKIM

Answer (score 1):

I also find that `spamassassin` SPF implementation is "bizarre"....
instead of `postfix-policyd-spf-perl` and `postfix-policyd-spf-python` that works *perfectly*.

For this reason I have

1. configured postfix to first check SPF using `postfix-policyd-spf-python`, blocking everything that violates SPF rules
2. then check mail content using spamassassin + its SPF rules

Installation:

```
apt install postfix-policyd-spf-python
```

then edit file `/etc/postfix/main.cf` inserting the `spf` filtering before spamassassin (amavis in my case):

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated,  reject_unauth_destination, check_policy_service unix:private/policy-spf, check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023
```

and add the following line in `/etc/postfix/master.cf`

```
policy-spf  unix  -       n       n       -       -       spawn user=nobody argv=/usr/bin/policyd-spf
```

then restart postfix and everything will work as expected!